# find minimum number of operations

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

There are two arrays of integers given, we have to find minimum number of operations to convert one array to another.

Operation is as follows:

if we decrease an element of array by 1 then all other elements increases by 1.

We have to find minimum number of such operations to change one array into another..

Example 
suppose initial array is 3 2 2
final array is 4 5 3

Minimum operations required is 5.

Explanation: 3 2 2 -> 2 3 3 -> 3 4 2 -> 2 5 3 -> 3 4 4 -> 4 5 3

Comment: Mapping is O(n), you want less than n ?

Comment: And if it can't be done? `{1,1} -> {2,2}`

Comment: Also a n-input, m-neuron, n-output feed-forward multi-layer neural network can do this making n*m + n*m calculations.

Comment: You can use hashtables as {1,1}-->{2,2} and can look at execution times to have an idea. Otherwise element-wise operations for all elements will make O(n)

Comment: Also, if that's the only operation, the number of operations it takes is set. All that would be left is to show whether or not it's actually possible.

Comment: I think you all are not getting the questions decreasing a elent by 1 increases all other element by 1

Comment: Possible if the mapping is 1-to-1 and the function is like procedural. Otherwise a neural network could learn that in O(n*m)

Comment: suppose an array is 3 2 2

Comment: the number of such operations will be 5

Comment: should i explain the intermediate steps???

Comment: @huseyin You probably missed everything except first line from task description. Neither mapping nor NN can't solve this task. But maybe i just don't catch the idea, could you explain some details how mapping can help (describe it as answer) ?

Comment: @andrei you are right I to dont think that mapping can do it

Comment: 3 2 2 -> 2 3 3 -> 3 4 2 -> 2 5 3 -> 3 4 4 -> 4 5 3

Comment: @Shubham I think it would be better if you delete your comments with explanations and move them to question as examples. Otherwise you have very low chances that anyone will read all history/will be able to help you.

Comment: @ShubhamChawla - What have you tried?

Comment: @mbeckish i created a formula k=s/(n-2) where s is sum of differences of two arrays

Comment: @andrei You are right I too was thinking the same

Answer (score 3):

Let N be the size of the arrays, A an B. For N=1, then any transformation is possible, and the number of steps is abs(A[0] - B[0]). For N=2, each operation increases one number and decreases the other. Then for a solution to exist we must have B[1] = A[1] - B[0] + A[0], and the number of operations is abs(A[0] - B[0]) (or equivalently abs(A[1] - B[1])).

For N > 2, consider the sum of all the elements in the array. Each step decreases one element by 1, and increases N-1 elements by 1. So the total increases by N-2.

Therefore, if it's possible to transform array A into array B using operations like this, then the number of steps will be (sum(B) - sum(A)) / (N-2). Call this T.

The operations commute, so to compute whether a transformation is possible, it's enough to figure out how many times each element gets decremented. If the i'th element gets decremented n_i times, then it gets incremented T-n_i times. So B[i] = A[i] - n_i + T - n_i, and therefore n_i = (A[i] - B[i] + T) / 2.

That's everything we need: a solution will exist if (sum(B) - sum(A)) is divisible by N-2, and calling T = (sum(B) - sum(A) / (N-2), we also need that A[i] - B[i] + T is divisible by 2 and non-negative for each i.

Note, there's no choice in any of this: if a solution exists it's unique up to the ordering of the operations.

Comment: What if sum(A)==sum(B)??

Comment: take example 1 2 3 and 3 2 1

Comment: @ShubhamChawla Then it is impossible. There is no solution.

Comment: @ShubhamChawla I give the general conditions for the existence of a solution in the answer. For 1,2,3 and 3,2,1 we have T=0, and n_0 = (1 - 3) / 2 = -1, which is negative. Therefore there's no solution.

Comment: @songlj yes, you're right. The case N=1, 2 have different solutions. I  added these to my answer.

Comment: Nitpick to edit: If `N=1`, it's only possible if `A[0]>B[0]`, since the only operation possible is decrease.

Answer (score 1):

First change each element to the negation of how far it has to go to each its target (i.e. subtract each element in the final array from the initial array). Then we just have to get all 0s.

To do this, keep decreasing the maximum (a [heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29) might be a good idea here). Once all numbers go positive there's no solution.

Note that you needn't just decrease the numbers by one. You can safely decrease it all the way up to either 0 (if it's negative, it can still be decreased by one) or up to `(it's value + minimum's value)/2` (thus they'd meet in the middle)

And a 2-element array `[a,b]` is only valid if `a = -b`.

**Example:**

For `3 2 2` to `4 5 3`, we normalize to `3-4 5-2 3-2` = `-1 -3 -1`

Then we decrease `-1` giving us `-2 -2 0`
Then we decrease `0` giving us `-1 -1 -1`
Then we decrease `-1` giving us `-2 0 0`
Then we decrease `0` giving us `-1 -1 1`
Then we decrease `1` giving us `0 0 0`

And we're done.

Answer (score 0):

This is incredibly simple because you only asked what the minimum number of operations is. Since you don't ask for a generic algorithm to actually compute the steps along the way, you can do this quite easily in O(n) time if you simply examine what happens at each step of the operation.

First of all, notice how the sum of all elements changes as you perform an operation on it. Let's start with simple cases and move onto more complex cases.

Suppose we have an array of size 1, [1], and we perform an operation on the single element. It becomes [0]. So the sum of the array increases by -1 after each operation.

Now suppose we have an array of size 2, [1, 1] and we perform an operation targeting any of the two elements. It will become either [2, 0] or [0, 2]. So the sum of the array increases by 0 for each operation.

And for an array of size 3? [1, 1, 1] becomes [0, 2, 2] after performing an operation which targets the first element.

Maybe you can see the formula here which is a generalization of how the sum of the array changes which is dependent upon a single variable, the length of the array!

For any given array A, the formula to compute the change in sum is:

```
delta_sum = len(A) - 2
```

So what do we do with this delta sum? Well if paid close enough attention to your example you would notice that the number 5 you got is not just a random coincidence! The sum of [4, 5, 3] is 12 and the sum of [3, 2, 2] is 7. The difference between the two sums is 5. And if you remember, `delta_sum` for arrays of length 3 is always going to be +1. So what if we just did this? (python example)

```
def minOperations(A, B):
    return (sum(B) - sum(A)) / (len(A) - 2)
```

Astonishingly, this simple one-liner gives us the right answer for *most* arrays A, and B for which `len(A) == len(B)` Even empty arrays like A=[] and B=[] will return 0 from this function because 0/-2 is 0.

But wait...we have a few issues with our code! We are dividing a number by `len(A) - 2`. What if `len(A) - 2 == 0`? We will get a ZeroDivisionError unfortunately if our `delta_sum` turns out to be 0! How can we fix this problem? We can fix it by simply adding a special case for arrays of length 2.

What we essentially want to do is this:

1. Return 0 if the two arrays are exactly the same.
2. Else return absolute value of `(B[0] - A[0])` if two arrays have the same *sum* but different elements.
3. Else return `None` or some error because no solution is possible. e.g. [1, 1] -> [2, 2] as noted in the comments

Our *almost* finished code turns out to be the following:

```
def minOperations(A, B):
    if len(A) == 2: 
        if A == B: 
            return 0
        elif sum(A) == sum(B): 
            return abs(B[0] - A[0]) 
        else:
            return None
    return (sum(B) - sum(A)) / (len(A) - 2)
```

Unfortunately we still have some silly issues to deal with to perfect our code.

One of these issues is the case where you have two arrays A and B, and it is entirely impossible to transform A into B with the decrement operation.

For example consider the case where A = [-1] and B = [1]. With only the decrementing operator you described in your questions, there is no possible way to transform A into B! Our function will cleverly return '-2. In this case, where we are returning a *negative* number of operations (which is most likely both conceptually and practically impossible), we probably want to return `None` or some exception/error instead. We can do that through the following code.

```
result = (sum(B) - sum(A)) / (len(A) - 2)
return result if result >= 0 else None
```

And then we have another problem...What if array A = [1,2,3,4] and array B = [1,2,3,5]? Since our delta_sum is 2 and the difference in sums is 1, we will return 1 / 2 with integer division which is 0 in Python...So we also need to check if our result is equivalent to an integer and if it's not we are returning an invalid answer. We can do so in the following way:

```
result = float((sum(B) - sum(A))) / (len(A) - 2)
    return int(result) if result >= 0 and result == int(result) else None
```

To make your code more robust you can also add an assertion check to assure that the lengths of the two arrays are equivalent at the beginning of your code.

```
assert(len(A) == len(B))
```

And our finished code will look like this:

```
def minOperations(A, B):
    assert(len(A) == len(B))
    if len(A) == 2: 
        if A == B: 
            return 0
        elif sum(A) == sum(B): 
            return abs(B[0] - A[0]) 
        else:
            return None
    result = float((sum(B) - sum(A))) / (len(A) - 2)
    return int(result) if result >= 0 and result == int(result) else None
```